# PHP: Validate form on a page and then send data to another php page

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, post

`<input id="username" name="username" class="required" type="text">`

`<input id="email" name="email" class="required" type="text">`

I am trying to validate user input on the same page using `<form action="<?php $_SERVER['SELF']; ?>"` and then if the input is correct I need to send the **input values** + 2 *additional* variables to another php page, let's just call them:

```
<?php   
    $var1 = "var1";
    $var2 = "var2";
?>
```

I need a way to pass them over to the next page without using sessions/get/javascript. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you just need hidden inputs in your form?

Comment: How is the next page loaded after variables are checked?

Comment: I don't mind using hidden inputs. The problem is, how do I get the variable values over to the next php page?

Comment: I've posted 2 suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Without sessions/get/javascript I guess your only 2 option might be

```
header("location:your_next_page?var1=$var1&var2=$var2");
```

Must be used before any output

Or

Form page:

```
setcookie("var1", $var1, 0, '/');
setcookie("var2", $var2, 0, '/');
//load next page
```

Next page:

```
$var1 = $_COOKIE['var1'];
$var2 = $_COOKIE['var2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie or localStorage for saving value on browser and retrieve them from another page.